# What is the best way to show data from 2 different network requests using swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I currently have two network requests, one of which needs input from the other to start to fetch for data.  What is the best way to fetch and show data (in this case the data is an array for each network request) from both network requests in the same list.

Here is my code:

```
VStack {
    List(viewModel.work, id: \.id) { work in
        VStack {
            Text("(work.name)")
        }.onAppear {
            fetchMoneyAmount(workType: work.type)
        }
    
        ForEach(viewModel.moneyAmount, id: \.id) { moneyAmt in 
            Text("maxMoney: (moneyAmt.maxAmount)")
        }
    }
}
.onAppear {
    fetchWork()
}
```

My problem right now is the network request (fetchMoneyAmount) seems to be fetching the data  as each list item is displayed from the viewModel.work array.  Each work list tile has the same MoneyAmount value which should not be the case.  There should be different MoneyAmounts for each work tile.

I am not really sure how else to make the fetchMoneyAmount network request because it needs the the value generated from the first network request.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Each 'work' item has one 'moneyAmount' item in the JSON.  I need to get the moneyAmount from each of the work items and then display each of the moneyAmounts for the corresponding 'work' item.

Comment: "make the fetchMoneyAmount network request because it needs the the value generated from the first network request" You need to serialize them. The Combine framework is the best way, in my opinion. You need to collect _all_ the data and get it into the data model, and _that_ triggers the interface update.

Comment: Apart from my answer below I recomment you this article.It explains the chaining in detail: https://www.vadimbulavin.com/modern-networking-in-swift-5-with-urlsession-combine-framework-and-codable/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to simply create a `final class DataProvider: ObservableObject` class which executes both requests dependent on each oter. For this you have several options:

1. Combine to chain multiple requests.
2. Just nest both requests if they depend on each other.

In your SwiftUI view you declare the following property `@ObservedObject var dataProvider = DataProvider()`.

Now whenever your data provider publishes new data, your view gets redrawn automatically.

## Sample Code

It shows you how to link a data provider observble object to SwiftUI code displaying the result. Think about it like this:

"Whenever your view is re-drawn assume your data to be just ready to be consumed"

With this in mind you just need to code your view as if your data is already available in a local property. But the property is served by the data provider which tells the view when to update.

### DataProvider

With a few more lines you can extend the DataProvider to load a second request when the first one is finished.

```
class DataProvider: ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set) var emojis: [Emoji] = []

    private var cancellable: Any?
    private var urlSession = URLSession.shared

    func readEmojiData(url: URL) {

        cancellable = urlSession
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { self.emojisFromRawData($0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .assign(to: \.emojis, on: self)
    }
}
```

### View

```
import SwiftUI

struct EmojiGrid : View {

    @ObservedObject var dataProvider = DataProvider()
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .largeTitle) var spacing: CGFloat = 12
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .largeTitle) var size: CGFloat = 50

    private var columns: [GridItem] {
        [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: size))]
    }

    private var versions: [Emoji.Version] {
        Emoji.Version.allCases.map { $0 }.sorted().reversed()
    }

    init() {
        dataProvider.readEmojiData(url: URL("https://..."))
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: spacing, content: {
                    ForEach(dataProvider.emojis, id: \.id) { emoji in
                        Button(emoji.emoji, action: { print(emoji) })
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .frame(width: size, height: size, alignment: .center)
                    }
                })
                .padding([.trailing, .leading], spacing)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to setup the second network request which needs an input from the first network request, but still no luck.  What else would you suggest adding in your DataProvider class to embed the second network request?  Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: For some reason each work list tile still has the same MoneyAmount value which should not be the case. There should be different MoneyAmounts for each work tile.

Comment: You have to create one function for each request. these functions return a publisher which then can be joined together. See "Chaiing Requests" in https://www.vadimbulavin.com/modern-networking-in-swift-5-with-urlsession-combine-framework-and-codable/